# Sharepoint list loses its IssueID column when exported to Excel, why?

Tags: sharepoint, excel, internet-explorer

My team current uses a Sharepoint list to manage bugs, issues etc for the project.
I frequently use the "Export to Spreadsheet" feature in Sharepoint to manage the list from within Excel, where I can edit, update and sync at my leisure.

However, I just got given a shiny new PC, and now whenever I use this feature, the **IssueID** column disappears.

On my **old** PC, I get the following:

```
A     B     C
ID    ID    Title ..... etc
1     246   foo
2     258   bar
3     266   foobar
```

whereby column A would simply be an index of row numbers, and column B was the "true" IssueID.

On my **new** PC, I get the following

```
A     B     
ID    Title ..... etc
1     foo
2     bar
3     foobar
```

which means that I no longer have the corresponding unique ID for each line item - which is, frankly, useless !

Both of my PCs are Win XP, Excel 2003 and IE6 (i know, but it's company policy), connecting to the same Sharepoint site.

Can anyone point out where I might be going wrong ?

Many thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of frustration, I tried opening the Sharepoint site in Google Chrome browser, and clicking the link "Export to Spreadsheet" worked ! - So it's probably fair to presume that there's something off with my install of IE6 (no surprises there then)

Answer (score 1):

Check the SharePoint view you are importing from still has the ID column in place. Excel is just doing an http call to a url and then finding the table specified in the connection, so if something has changed it is most likely to be at the sharepoint side of things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, maybe I didn't explain well enough, but I can export the same list, at the same time, to 2 separate PCs and get different behaviour. So I can't see how this can be a Sharepoint-related issue.

Comment: Do you get different html back from each machine?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have cause of this issue in SharePoint 2010

I have done some testing in IE 9 and found that including the "Content Type" column in a view seems to break the Export to Excel feature.  I'd be interested to see if anyone can reproduce this behavior.

Tested in Firefox = Identical behavior
Tested in Chrome and could not get the Export to Excel feature to work.

If anyone can confirm this I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a broser/system related problem. The sharepoint administrator may exclude the taskid column from the list view. You can contact him for the help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, maybe I didn't explain well enough, but I can export the same list, at the same time, to 2 separate PCs and get different behaviour. So I can't see how this can be a Sharepoint-related issue.